# From a set of nodes, get all nodes in the set that are not a child of a node in that set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node, let's say person, that owns nodes. I want to get all nodes owned by that person that are not a child of a node owned by that person. Also, a child could be multiple levels deep (i.e. if A is child of B and B is child of C then A is child of C).

For example, if we have

```
   A <-[:CHILD_OF]- B <-[:CHILD_OF]- C            E <-[:CHILD_OF]- F
   ^
   |
[:CHILD_OF]
   |
   D
```

and person owns A, F, D, and C, then only A and F should return because D is child of A and C is child of A

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
MATCH (person)-[:OWNS]->(owned) WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT owned) AS owned
RETURN FILTER(x in owned WHERE ALL (y in owned WHERE NOT ((x)-[:CHILD_OF*..20]->(y)))) AS children
```

But if a child is more than 20 levels deep, this query will return it. I could use [:CHILD_OF*] to match infinite number of [:CHILD_OF] relationships, but that might get slow if I have many levels of nodes. Is there a better query to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the function `shortestPath`:

```
MATCH (person)-[:OWNS]->(owned) WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT owned) AS owned
FILTER(x IN owned WHERE ALL (
    y IN owned WHERE NOT CASE WHEN shortestPath((x)-[:CHILD_OF*]->(y)) IS NULL
                              THEN TRUE 
                              ELSE FALSE 
                         END
)) AS children
```